# Check if a string has multiple '.' characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm allowing users to upload a file, however I need to check if the file has a proper name (since using multiple '.' characters throws off the .split() method). Here's what I have so far:

```
//Check if filename has more than 1 period character in the whole thing. 
if(this.file.name.???){
  this.fileNameAccepted = true;
} else {
  this.fileNameAccepted = false;
}
```

Comment: OP posted question and answer simultaneously. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Completely normal https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @CertainPerformance Learnt something new today

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava self-answering is allowed and not a bad thing, but if it's something like this, i don't know if i like it or not. Anyways, `if(!/\.[\s\S]*\./.test(this.file.name)) /*...*/`

Answer (score -1):

```
let fileNameSplit = this.file.name.split('.');
```

The `.split()` method returns another array element for each '.' it finds. So `fileNameSplit` will have two elements if there are no '.' characters in the filename (there is automatically a '.' at the end of a filename before the file extension, ie *hello-world.jpg*, where it will always split a filename). A filename with 2 periods in the name (and 1 before the extension) will return 4 elements.

Use `fileNameSplit[fileNameSplit.length - 1]` to determine the last element (the file extension).